# Getting statistical information for a single replicate (AnyLogic)

Tags: parameters, statistics, anylogic

I did my Simulation using AnyLogic and I saved the required variables in a dataset e.g. the time that the patient takes to move from a queue to a delay.

Now, I want to do several replicates and extract the mean of the waiting time for each replicate.
I created "Parameters Variation" from the Experment Option and I created a dataset in the ParametersVariation. Then I wrote in the "After Iteration" bar the following code:

```
dataset.add(agent.getBlockEnterTime());
```

I thought that in the ParametersVaraition he will be able to take the information from the main.

I need to know for example, how to get the mean of the waiting time in a queue at each replicate and save them in a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Simply make sure to write your code in the "After simulation run" code box in the ParameterVariation experiment properties
2. Amend your code to `dataset.add(root.agent.getBlockEnterTime());` . `root` refers to your Main so if you have an instance named `agent` on Main and that you can call `getBlockEnterTime` on it, it will work

Check the example models such as "Bass Diffusion" to see how it works

Comment: Thank You. But it tells me " root can`t be resolved" !! any suggestions?

Comment: You are not writing it in the correct code box, see my point 1 (or share a screenshot for further clarification)

Comment: I have now the following problem: "agent cant be resolved". I wrote the code in (After simulation run)

Comment: Then you do not have an instance called "agent" on main. Check my point 2 :) Hence screenshots and descriptions of your model setup would help ;-)